# How does the custom loss function gets calculated in binary classification problem?

Tags: h2o

I created a custom loss function for a binary (0/1) classification problem in h2o via Python as shown below. The idea is to minimize total cost based on true positive, true negative, false positive, and false negative. Here are the questions that I hope to get an answer on:

- What is used to calculate custom loss function? I used the output of confusion matrix of training data and validation data and manually calculate the value of the loss function but it doesn't match the output. Note that the default metrics used to generate confusion matrix is using `f1` threshold
- On h2o [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/custom_metric_func.html), `custom_metric_func` can be used in GLM, DRF, and GBM. However, it doesn't work in GLM (the loss function value is default to 0) although it works perfectly in GBM. Any idea on why that's the case?

Custom loss function:

```py
class CustomLossFunc:
    def map(self, predicted, actual, weight, offset, model):
        import math
        cost_tp = -9
        cost_tn = 0
        cost_fp = 1
        cost_fn = 10

        y = actual[0]
        y_pred = predicted[0] # [class, p0, p1]

        if (y == 0) and (y_pred == 0):
            total_cost = cost_tn
        elif (y == 0) and (y_pred == 1):
            total_cost = cost_fp
        elif (y == 1) and (y_pred == 1):
            total_cost = cost_tp
        else:
            total_cost = cost_fn

        return [total_cost, 1]

    def reduce(self, left, right):
        return [left[0] + right[0], left[1] + right[1]]

    def metric(self, last):
        return last[0]
```

The loss function is uploaded using `h2o.upload_custom_metric()` then I run GLM and GBM for comparison:

```py
# GLM
glm_fit_cost = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family='binomial',
                                             model_id='glm_fit_cost',
                                             #standardize=True,
                                             custom_metric_func= cost_loss_func)
glm_fit_cost.train(x=x_co,
                   y=y_co,
                   training_frame = train_co_h2o,
                   validation_frame = valid_co_h2o)

# GBM
gbm_mod = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(model_id = "gbm_mod",
                                       custom_metric_func = cost_loss_func)
gbm_mod.train(y=y_co,
              x=x_co,
              training_frame=train_co_h2o,
              validation_frame = valid_co_h2o)
```

I have tried the following:

- Debug via manual calculation using confusion matrix of the training set and validation set and compare to the output of the loss function

Reference for the example used to create my own loss function:

- [Resource1](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/custom_metric_func/CustomMetricFuncClassification.ipynb)
- [Resource2](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/custom_metric_func.html)

Comment: can you redo the calculations using the prediction results directly, instead of the confusion matrix output and then see if your results match up. there is a bug in the confusion matrix that you can track here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5243. Can you also post what version of H2O-3 that you are using? thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Lauren. I did what you suggested and use the prediction results directly and turned out that the value obtained is close to the output of custom loss function (still has discrepancy but better than using confusion matrix directly). I am using H2O 3.24.0.4 and python 3.6.8. Any idea on why custom loss function does not work in GLM? It works fine in GBM but not GLM.